# Multiple Independent level of security vs Multi-level security

Tags: networking, operating-systems

I am looking for a way to isolate two different networks from each other. Suppose we have 2 different network (public and private). I am looking for a way to connect to these two network via single network wire in a trusted way. I did some search and I find that there are two solution for this purpose: 1)Multi-level security 2)MILS. Unfortunately I could not find any obvious difference between these two methods. I also found out that MILS used separation kernel for making different networks independent. Would you please explain these two method and their differences for me? Also would you please tell me what is the relation between cross domain solutions and these two methods? Is there any opensource solution available for these methods?

Regards.

Comment: Maybe you should start with defining more in depth what you are trying to do. So you have a public and a private network. What are you using these networks for? What sorts of data or devices do you need to secure on the private network? What sort of budget for devices are you looking at? What sort of infrastructure will this be in?

Comment: I want to isolate data in private network from public network. This isolation is in network, Ram and even CPU. For this purpose we should guarantee time and space isolation. There is no extra hardware needed for this purpose. These solutions usually are embedded in OS.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you will have a storage device on two different networks, and you want the public network to be able to access data subset A and the private network to access data subset B and not be able to access each other's data? If that isn't the case, you'll still have to be more specific as to what you are trying to do (include user groups, netgroups, domains, subnets, etc) involved.

Comment: Something like that but not that simple. I want to subset A and B was isolate from other resources too. (RAM,CPU and etc) please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_single-level

Comment: Then lets start with what protocol/method you plan to have users access this shared storage. If you will be using something like FTP, SMB, NFS or HTTP, there is no need to worry about the CPU or RAM on the host machine as it will not be accessible via these protocols.

Comment: I am not worry about these protocols, I am worry about a third party Trojan that could access to memory blocks or cpu during data communication.